# Get specific object from a list with a certain parameter

Tags: list, python

I have a list of Account objects in `self.accounts`, and I know that only one of them will have a `type` attribute equal to 'equity'.  What is the best (most pythonic) way to get only that object from the list?

Currently I have the following, but I'm wondering if the `[0]` at the end is superfluous.  Is there a more succinct way to do this?

`return [account for account in self.accounts if account.type == 'equity'][0]`

Comment: No, it's not superfluous, because it determines whether you return a list (with possibly zero or more elements in it) or just the first element in that list (and assuming it's not empty). If that's what you want, it's fairly succinct.

Comment: What I meant by superfluous was wrapping in a list only to pull it right back out.  The way I had it, I knew it was necessary, but I was looking for a way to skip that step.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
return next(account for account in self.accounts if account.type == 'equity')
```

or

```
return (account for account in self.accounts if account.type == 'equity').next()
```

Answer (score 4):

"Pythonic" means nothing. There is probably not any more "Succinct" solution than yours, no.

Ignacios solution has the benefit of stopping once it finds the item. Another way of doing it would be:

```
def get_equity_account(self):
    for item in self.accounts:
        if item.type == 'equity':
            return item
    raise ValueError('No equity account found')
```

Which perhaps is more readable. Readability is Pythonic. :)

Edit: Improved after martineaus suggestions. Made it into a complete method.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `for item in self.accounts:`, not `for item in self.accounts[0]:`, to be a translation of the OP's code?

Comment: I also think the `break` should be a `return item` and that the `for` should have an `else:` clause or something following it to indicate 'not found'.

Comment: You are correct about the [0] being incorrect. The other suggestions are good too, although an `else` isn't needed if we use `return`.

Answer (score 0):

It's such a common need in Python but afaik there is no built in way to do it. You could also do:

```
return next(filter(lambda x: x.type == 'equity', self.accounts))
```